# Schema Error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: incomplete input when adding a trigger to check return if a date is in the future

Tags: sqlite

Here is my current sqllite code to create the database:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    user_id INT,
    channel_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE credits(
    user_id INT,
    number_of_items INT CHECK(number_of_items > 0),
    expiration DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, number_of_items, expiration),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE users_items(
    user_id INT,
    item_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```

and here is the code for the trigger I am trying to make

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_has_enough_credits_to_monitor_item
BEFORE INSERT ON users_items
BEGIN
   SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_items WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) >=
            (SELECT sum(number_of_items) FROM credits WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND expiration >= datetime('now'))
         THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'No more items allowed')
     END;
END;
```

In my database, each user has credits which are stored in the `credits` table. These credits allow for a certain number of items in `users_items`, but also these credits have an expiration associated with them. I want to generate a trigger that will prevent a user from adding a record to `user_items` if they do not have enough credits (that have not yet expired), but I get the following errors on my [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kNcpTN1neadgPJsAmh4pzL/1):

```
Schema Error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: incomplete input
Schema Error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: cannot commit - no transaction is active
```